# Are there any side effects from using Win32 16-bit registry API's?

Tags: winapi, registry

I have some code that opens a registry key using `RegOpenKey`. Turns out this is wrong as MSDN says:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724895(v=vs.85).aspx

```
Note  This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit
versions of Windows. Applications should use the RegOpenKeyEx function.
```

Could there be any side effects from using this API instead of `RegOpenKeyEx`? I only ask as some code using this API also calls `RegQueryInfoKey` which returns an astronomically large amount of subkeys when there are only 2 intermittently.

Comment: `RegOpenKey` internally calls `RegOpenKeyEx` so calling `RegOpenKey` should not matter.

Comment: You can't provide the *samDesired* argument.  Well, yes, that matters a great deal with UAC around to say No!  Focus on your real problem instead.

Comment: So then why is RegQueryInfoKey  returning bad information?

Comment: @paulm : show the relevant parts of your code. Did you check if `RegQueryInfoKey` returns ERROR_SUCCESS ?

Comment: I check all errors, I'll post the snippet later

Answer (score 0):

No.  The deprecated functions do not provide all the functionality of the newer ones, so they might or might not meet your needs, but to the best of my knowledge using the old functions does not have any side-effects.  (That is, it does not cause the newer functions to misbehave.)

Be that as it may, you should follow the advice in MSDN and replace the deprecated functions with the modern equivalents.  In this case it should not be difficult to do so.  Then, assuming the problems you are experiencing still occur, you can at least stop worrying that this might be the cause.